A student who plays basketball but likes to read
I am looking for a movie I saw about 15 years ago on TV.
There was a student who came to a university (I guess) because the university wanted him to play in the local basketball team. As a student accepted because of his sport skills, he was not expected to excel in normal subjects so he got a personal teacher (a girl from the university) who was supposed to help him with the studies.
I remember that she gave him a couple of books to read, without any expectation, but when he actually read them she started to change her opinion on him. The story goes on and I guess that in the end he quit basketball, as he realized what is really important (knowledge, love, blah blah :D). Even though the movie is quite average, I would like to see it again as I remember that I liked it a lot.
Some additional info (hopefully true):

American production.
From the 90s.
It is a normal movie, not an animated one.


Could it be One on One? This is an earlier movie (1977), starring Robby Benson as a small town kid who gets a scholarship for his basketball skills, but being unprepared for the rigors of university, he is assigned a girl tutor who helps him with reading as well as life. The star, Robby Benson, released an autobiography in 2012 called I Am Not Dead...Yet about his life in film and surviving multiple open-heart surgeries. 


Sounds like Finding Forrester

Because of scoring exceptionaly high on a state wide standardized exam and being an exceptionally good basketball player Jamal Wallace is sent to a prestigious prep school in Manhattan. He soon befriends the reclusive writer, William Forrester. The friendship leads to William to overcome his reclusivness and for Jamal to overcome the racial prejudices and pursue his true dream - writing.


There is no girl tutor in that movie however, and I think it was far above average as movies go! 

The "tutor" was actually his (future) girlfriend who gave him books to read, and became his girlfriend when he commented intelligently on them.
